# IN/NOT IN functions not working in Marketing Cloud SQL query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm running into this strange issue without being able to understand why it is happening. I want to run this simple query:

```
select a.[Account:PersonContact:Id]
from [Salesforce_Data_Event_DE] as a
join Account_Salesforce_3 as b on a.[Account:Id] = b.[Id]
where a.[Account:Id] not in (select s.Account__c from SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce as s)
```

the result is 0 rows. The problem is that, if I run the exact same query with the *IN* function:

```
select a.[Account:PersonContact:Id]
from [Salesforce_Data_Event_DE] as a
join Account_Salesforce_3 as b on a.[Account:Id] = b.[Id]
where a.[Account:Id] in (select s.Account__c from SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce as s)
```

the result is still 0 rows.
If I remove the *WHERE* condition, I can find more or less 36k rows as a result.
If I run the nested query separately:

```
select s.Account__c from SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce as s
```

the result is more or less 150k rows.

I cannot explain why this is happening and I would like to ask you if there is a possible explanation for this issue since *NOT IN* function is used in many queries on my Business Unit and if something changed I will have to rework them all.

Of course, if I write the query this way it works fine:

```
select s.Account__c
from SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce as s
inner join [Salesforce_Data_Event_DE] as a on a.[Account:Id] = s.[Account__c]
```

and the result is about 1.4k rows.

Do you know if something changed about the *NOT IN* and *IN* functions? Or can you notice a mistake I've made on the query?

Thank you,
Francesco

---

I will try to explain myself better:

```
select a.[Account:PersonContact:Id]
from [Salesforce_Data_Event_DE] as a
join Account_Salesforce_3 as b on a.[Account:Id] = b.[Id]
```

this query result is 36k rows. Now I want to exclude from these 36k records all those who are inside another DE (SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce), so I run the following query:

```
select a.[Account:PersonContact:Id]
from [Salesforce_Data_Event_DE] as a
join Account_Salesforce_3 as b on a.[Account:Id] = b.[Id]
where a.[Account:Id] not in (select s.Account__c from SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce as s)
```

the result is now 0 rows. So we can think that everyone in the 36k is in the DE called SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce. At this point, I would expect that, if I run the query with the *IN* statement the result will be of 36k since everyone is into this DE:

```
select a.[Account:PersonContact:Id]
from [Salesforce_Data_Event_DE] as a
join Account_Salesforce_3 as b on a.[Account:Id] = b.[Id]
where a.[Account:Id] in (select s.Account__c from SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce as s)
```

also this query gives as a result 0 rows.

Thus the *IN/NOT IN* statement is not working properly or I've made a mistake I still cannot find!

Comment: Does below produce any result?
select a.[Account:PersonContact:Id]
from [Salesforce_Data_Event_DE] as a
join Account_Salesforce_3 as b on a.[Account:Id] = b.[Id]

Comment: Inside of you IN/NOT IN you are also joining (default is inner join) on `Account_Salesforce_3`  so it is possible there are records that match between `Salesforce_Data_Event_DE` and `SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce` but they do not exist on `Account_Salesforce_3` - which would cause 0 results returned. Have you checked to see results returned if you remove the In/Not In statement?

Comment: @MateuszBartkowiak yes, it returns 1.4k rows

@Gortonington every record in  `Salesforce_Data_Event_DE` exists on `Account_Salesforce_3` since it is a subset of the Account. I've checked to see results returned if I remove the IN/NOT IN statement and the query returns 36k rows. With both the IN and the NOT IN statements it returns 0 rows and it has no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

Debugging tSQL without working of the same dataset is difficult and hence I can only give a guess.

However, based on your description my guess, even if it is unlikely, is that the following return `NULL` values which could explain what you see:

```
SELECT s.Account__c 
FROM   SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce AS s
```

> An `IN` statement will be parsed identically to `field=val1` or
> `field=val2`. Having a `NULL` value results in `field=null` which will
> not work. A `NOT IN` query will not return any rows if any `NULLs` exists in the list of `NOT IN` values.

You can explicitly exclude `NULL` by using `IS NOT NULL` as below.

```
SELECT s.Account__c 
FROM   SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce AS s
WHERE  s.Account__c IS NOT NULL
```

Or you can try to use `NOT EXISTS` instead

```
SELECT A.[Account:PersonContact:Id]
FROM   [Salesforce_Data_Event_DE] A
JOIN   Account_Salesforce_3 AS B ON A.[Account:Id] = B.[Id]
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT S.Account__c 
           FROM SurveyTaker__c_Salesforce S
           WHERE A.[Account:Id] = S.Account__c
       )
```

If this is working, the reason is because of a `NULL` return.
Here is an article to read about the [three-valued-logic](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/) and why SQL behaves like this.

In a nutshell:

A `WHERE` clause must evaluate as `true` in order to be returned but this is not possible with `NOT IN` when `NULL` is present.

`'B' NOT IN ('X','Y',NULL)` is equivalent to `'B' <> 'X' AND 'B' <> 'Y' AND 'B' <> NULL`

**Result:**

```
'B' <> 'X' = True
'B' <> 'Y' = True 
'B' <> NULL = Unknown
```

True AND True AND Unknown evaluates as Unknown and hence you see `0` results.